Windows Notification Chiming Sounds while Using Computer
I have a Windows 11 Desktop Machine. I randomly hear chime notification sounds, similar to a USB device being plugged in.I've tried disabling all notifications and it still keeps happening.
This computer is left powered on all the time, and I randomly keep hearing these notifications while using computer. How can I fix this issue?
